# Wordpress site in subfolder of another wordpress site .htaccess issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a wordpress site in a folder
/site1
That site is site1.com

I have another wordpress site (totally separate install) in a subfolder of that site
/site1/site2
That site is site2.com

Ideally I would like to be able to access this site by typing either of these two things...

site1.com/site2
or
site2.com

So far, that works. However, I can't do something that's really important.

I can't type, say
**site2.com/forums** and get to my forums. I get an **internal server error**. The only way to get to the forums is to go all the way back to site1.com/site2/forums

Can someone tell me what needs to change in my .htacces, wp-config, or wordpress dashboard to make this happen (and in what subfolder to make these changes?)

.htaccess for site1

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

.htaccess for site2

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site2/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /site2/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

As stated in the comments, both the wp url and site url are http://site1.com/site2 as doing anything else broke the sites.

Comment: Unless you tell what is currently there in the config files, nope!!

Comment: Right now in the dashboard->settings I have them configured as http://site1.com/site2 for both the wordpress url and the site url.  Doing anything else breaks things, so that's my default config. I'll edit  the question to show the .htaccess for both folders.